# Issue in running a dynamic web project tomcat "Only a type can be imported. org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration resolves to a package"

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, tomcat, web

I am trying to migrate an old Web project ( jsp /java) on eclipse. Created a new Dynamic web project. Copied all the code in respective folders and converted the project into a Maven project and added all the required dependencies. Resolved all compiled time errors. When I am running the project on tomcat through eclipse getting following errors.

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: [18] in the generated java file: [/home/xxx/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/work/Catalina/localhost/webadmin/org/apache/jsp/login_jsp.java]
Only a type can be imported. org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration resolves to a package 

Apr 19, 2019 2:21:03 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] threw exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.login_jsp
```

Issue looks to be something related to configuration only. Tried removing conflicts from pom files , tried at all different paths of  hibernate.cfg. used latest possible version of jars in pom

First few lines of web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="4.0">

  <display-name>webapp</display-name>
   <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>login.jsp</welcome-file>

  </welcome-file-list>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>sessionfilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class> com.blossom.action.SessionFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>sessionfilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>album_insert</display-name>
    <servlet-name>album_insert</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.xxx.action.album_insert</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>album_insert</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/album_insert</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

poi.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>webadmin</groupId>
  <artifactId>webadmin</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <dependencies>



<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>catalina</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.53</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
    <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.9</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.ezmorph</groupId>
    <artifactId>ezmorph</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.6</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
    <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.2</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.0</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.servlets</groupId>
    <artifactId>cos</artifactId>
    <version>05Nov2002</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>    
</dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Build Path

```
1. Tomcat 9.0
2. EAR Libary
3. JRE (java 8 oracle)
4. Maven dependencies
5. Web app libraries
```

The program should run without error

Comment: Be sure you have a JEE runtime library included into your Eclipse project.

Comment: If it's saying that that matches a package name, so actually look through the project build path, all of it, and see if there is one. Determine if this is a false error or not.

Comment: This reminds me of https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=47323 but that issue was observed on Windows (that uses a case-insensitive file system). I think @nitind is right.

Answer (score 0):

Seems there's a version mismatch here, `tomcat 9` but `catalina 6.0.53`.
Catalina dependency needs to be upgraded, something like

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
  <artifactId>tomcat-catalina</artifactId>
  <version>9.0.19</version>
</dependency>
```

Looking for `catalina 6.0.53` on a maven repository shows a warning

> Note: This artifact was moved to:
>
> org.apache.tomcat » tomcat-catalina

Answer (score 0):

it was a deployment path issue.
After adding Maven dependencies in Properties->Deployment Assembly ->  Add ( Java Build Path Entries) -Maven Dependencies the issue is resolved .